# Delete post image attachments with jQuery from the front end

Tags: jquery, attachments, customization

In my WP 4.4 Twenty Sixteen child theme I want to delete post image attachments from a front end form created by a plugin. To achieve this I followed [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/36644/25187), but the delete links doesn't delete anything (they link me to the top of the page). What is wrong here?

**UPDATE** [SOLVED]

**With the commenters help and after fixing some errors I solved my problem.
Thank you! Below is the fixed code.**

In my front end form created by a plugin I get the post ID and display its image attachments together with the delete links:

```
<!-- Display item thumbnails -->
<?php if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && isset( $_POST['postid'] ) ) {
    $images = get_children( array ( 'post_parent' => $_POST['postid'], 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image' ));
    if ( empty( $images ) ) {
        // no attachments here
    } else {
        echo '<label for="item_thumbnails">Post thumbnails</label>';
        echo '<div class="item_thumbnails">';
        foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail' ) . '<br>'; ?>
            <!-- add a 'Delete' link -->
            <a class="remImage" name="<?php echo $attachment_id; ?>" href="#"><?php _e('delete');?></a>
            <input type="hidden" id="att_remove" name="att_remove[]" value="<?php echo $attachment_id; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="nonce" id="nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'delete_attachment' ); ?>" />
        <?php }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}?>
```

In a 'js' subdirectory of my plugin I created a jQuery script named 'delete_attachment.js':

```
// this is for jQuery 1.7+
//jQuery('.remImage').on('click', function(event) {

// this is for jQuery 1.4.3+
jQuery(document).delegate('.remImage', 'click', function(event) {

// this is for jQuery 1.3+ (deprecated)
//jQuery('.remImage').live('click', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    var attID = jQuery(this).attr('name');
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            action: 'delete_attachment',
            attID: jQuery(this).attr('name'),
            _ajax_nonce: jQuery('#nonce').val(),
            post_type: 'attachment'
        },
        success: function() {
            console.log('#file-'+attID)
            jQuery('#file-'+attID).fadeOut();    
        }
    });
})
```

I enqueued it in the plugin file:

```
function the_plugin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'delete-attachment', plugins_url( 'js/delete_attachment.js' , __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
    wp_localize_script( 'delete-attachment', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'the_plugin_scripts' );
```

and in the same plugin file I added a function that handles the AJAX request:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_delete_attachment', 'delete_attachment' );
function delete_attachment( $post ) {
    //echo $_POST['attID'];
    $msg = 'Attachment ID [' . $_POST['attID'] . '] has been deleted!';
    if( wp_delete_attachment( $_POST['attID'], true )) {
        echo $msg;
    }
    die();
}
```

Comment: [You need to prevent the default click action on your links](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/). Do you get any sort of error in your javascript console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you need to handle the [AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) call in PHP.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_delete_attachment', 'delete_attachment' );
function delete_attachment( $post ) {
//echo $_POST['att_ID'];
$msg = 'Attachment ID [' . $_POST['att_ID'] . '] has been deleted!';
if( wp_delete_attachment( $_POST['att_ID'], true )) {
    echo $msg;
}
die();
}
```

As for your event, just add it to the click function then everything inside will know what you're talking about.

```
jQuery('.remImage').on('click', function(event) {
```

---

TESTING [AJAX](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action))

Copy and paste this into your functions. It will automatically run and should output a response from the AJAX in an alert and also the console.

---

```
function ajax_delete_attachment_handler() {

    $data = json_encode(array('message' => 'THIS IS AJAX WORKING', '$_POST' => $_POST));
    wp_send_json_success($data);
}

$action_name = 'delete_attachment';
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_$action_name", 'ajax_delete_attachment_handler');
add_action("wp_ajax_$action_name", 'ajax_delete_attachment_handler');
add_action('wp_footer', function() {
    ?>
    <script>
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: {
                action: 'delete_attachment',
                ID: 'some ID here',
                'foo': 'bar'
            },
            success: function (response) {

                // we encoded the data, so let's decode it first
                var json = JSON.parse(response.data);

                console.log('response: ', response);
                console.log('json parsed: ', json);

                alert(response.data);
            },
            fail: function (response) {
                console.log('FAILED: ' + response);
            }
        });
    </script>
    <?php
});
```

Comment: Your answer helped me to solve my problem, so I will mark it as accepted, but please fix the code line `fjQuery('.remImage').on('click', function(event) {` as in my updated question, because the `on('click'` doesn't work. Thank you!

Comment: Well, if it's working then just roll with it. Cheers!

Comment: Changed `.live()` with `.delegate()` - `jQuery( document ).delegate('.remImage', 'click', function(event) {` as suggested on http://api.jquery.com/live/.